# postgres function 101: returning text

Tags: postgresql

I have a function like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION current_name()
RETURNS text AS 'select foo;' LANGUAGE sql;
```

Except it doesn't work. Neither does `RETURN TEXT "SELECT 'foo';"`

How can I keep it written in SQL, but still return text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is the least change you need to make it work.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION current_name()
RETURNS text AS 
'select ''foo''::text;'
LANGUAGE sql;
```

You'll see that the SQL statement--the body of the function--is a string. Strings have to be quoted, and single quotes within a quoted string have to be escaped. Soon you have more quotation marks than actual text.

The usual way to write something like this is to use a [dollar quoted string constant](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-DOLLAR-QUOTING).

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION current_name()
RETURNS text AS 
$$
  select 'foo'::text;
$$
LANGUAGE sql;
```